# Pandas python: transposing a single column and assigning already given data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe called dfSocial:

```
  age     gender    impressions
0 13-17   female    234561
1 13-17   male      34574
2 25-34   female    120665
3 25-34   male      234560
4 35-44   female    5134
5 35-44   male      2405
6 45-54   female    423
7 45-54   male      324
```

Now I want to make a new dataframe that comes out like this:

```
  age     male      female
0 13-17   34574     234561
1 25-34   234560    120665
2 35-44   2405      5134
3 45-55   324       423
```

Can anybody help to get this transformation.
I have tried with the following code:

```
        for gender in ["male", "female"]:
        dfSocialByGender = dfSocial[dfSocial['gender'].str.match(gender)]
        if not dfSocialByGender.empty:
            dfSocial[f'{gender}Performance'] = dfSocialByGender.groupby(["age"])['impressions'].sum()
```

However this get the values of 0, all help is appreciated!
I have tried doing the code like this:

```
        for gender in ["male", "female"]:
          dfSocialByGender = dfSocial[dfSocial['gender'].str.match(gender)]
          if not dfSocialByGender.empty:
            dfSocial[f'{gender}Performance'] = dfSocialByGender.['impressions'].sum()
```

However this get a total sum of the impressions for male and female and not dividing by age group.

Comment: Why not use `pivot_table` with `sum`?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: `df = df.pivot_table(index='age', columns='gender', values='impressions', aggfunc='sum')`